# Deferred export in EcmaScript modules (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, module, export

Is it possible to perform deferred export in EcmaScript modules (after executing some async operations in importing script, for example)?

```js
function do_export() {
    export default class AsyncClass {
        constructor() {
            this.name = "Async Class";
        }
    }
}

setTimeout(do_export, 500);
```

Comment: Are you expecting a module that imports this module to wait for the export to be set, or would it get `undefined` until the timer runs?

Comment: I expect to wait: `import("./path/to/AsyncClass.js").then(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not like this, both `import` and `export` are expected to evaluate in one go. Export can never be invoked later. Think about it this way: what should happen if `do_export` is called a second time?

However `import` can be used as a function:

```
const promise = import("module-name");
const module_name = await promise;
```

Which means you can defer import of your module until it's needed.

An alternative to deferring export, as you wanted to, is to return Promise, that's what promises are for:

```
export default new Promise((resolve) => {
  setTimeout(()=>{
    class AsyncClass {
      constructor() {
        this.name = "Async Class";
      }
    }
    resolve(AsyncClass);
  }, 500);
});
```

Now you can import the module immediately, but have to await on the value in your program:

```
import AsyncClass from "./AsyncClass.js";


(async ()=>{
    const instance = new (await AsyncClass)();
    console.log(instance.name);
})();
```